# Configuring dojo in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dojo

How do I configure Dojo in Eclipse? Is there any plugins?
What are the steps for doing the same? I am using eclipse ganymede.I get a error when I try using the ATF

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ATF is actively being developed.  You might try Aptana.  Otherwise, using Dojo just amounts to loading a directory in your project.  Most JS tools beyond that probably have little to do with Dojo

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Eclipse Ajax Toolkit Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/atf/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific plugin, but the DOJO Foundation has released an own IDE for it: http://maqetta.org/